# bitcoin-cli very slow to respond to RPC calls (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: json-rpc, raspberry-pi, bitcoin-cli

Running Bitcoin 0.11 on Raspberry Pi 2 (Quad core 900MHz 1GB RAM, 128GB Flash Drive for blockchain, 8GB SD Card for OS and software).

Blockchain is fully synced, 13 connections.
In htop, I see I'm around 700/862MB RAM, 1/99MB Swap. 1 processor is up around 90% but the other 3 are down in the <5% range.

I SSH into the pi (running bitcoind, no GUI) and some commands take forever to get a response. Sometimes `getinfo` or `getpeerinfo` will take 30-60 seconds to print out. `gettxoutsetinfo` takes way longer: almost ten minutes!! I don't see any resources being maxed out in htop during this time.

I know this is a low-power machine, maybe the UTXO set hash in the `gettxoutsetingo` command is what's specifically taking so long in that case.

Can I adjust any settings either in the RPi OS or bitcoin.conf to get snappier performance? Ideally I would like to run a few python scripts that use RPC, triggered by bitcoin's `blocknotify=...`

Comment: I'm guessing it is hardware, however `gettxoutsetinfo` is supposed to take a while. I switched my node over to a spare PC (3ghz 4gb ram)as my node, it responds much quicker to the `getinfo` `getmininginfo` and other RPC calls, less than 1 second.

Comment: 1 GB of RAM seems low for bitcoind, and 99 MB of swap doesn't help much.  `top` should show a state for the `bitcoind` process.  If it's in state R most of the time, then CPU is probably the bottleneck.  If state D, then it may be I/O (including swapping / paging).

Comment: There's about 15 "bitcoind" threads and most are in state S. One is in state D.

Comment: I can't contribute much to the resolution of that problem, except stating that I have the exact same (with RPi 2 running Raspbian Jessie, headless). In my case `bitcoin-cli gettxoutsetinfo` doesn't even return anything but an empty dict. I guess it times out or something, but it does this at highly varying intervals, sometimes after 5 minutes, in one extreme case after almost 40 minutes.

Comment: I filed a ticket on github/bitcoin and got 1 reaction saying that on a RPi 2 average response time was around 7 minutes. With results! Not an empty dict like I'm getting. The difference is that my Bitcoind is compiled with the `--disable-wallet` option.

Are you running a wallet on your Bitcoin install?

Comment: If you are using an auth cookie instead of explicitly setting the `rpcuser` and `rpcpassword` in your `bitcoin.conf` - then it is slower I have noticed.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same set up and getinfo for me takes about 10-20s initially but then takes ~5s there after. (I need to restart the daemon periodically as it crashes for some reason). I'm running 0.11.1 and haven't made any special tweaks. gettxoutsetinfo takes around 12 minutes. CPU, RAM and Swap comparable with what you have as well.

Hardware is probably the most obvious limitation. You could overclock the Pi CPU but I doubt it will drastically reduce the response time though.

Comment: I've had the same problem with crashes when using version 0.11.x. I recommend updating to v0.13.x and daemon won't crash anymore.